# NameError: name 'num1 is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
line 24, in <module>
    if not num1.isdigit():
NameError: name 'num1' is not defined
>>>
```

that's the error that's being displayed, and I believe this is the section causing it(ofc I had to put parentheses <3):

```
def main1(self):
    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
if not num1.isdigit():
     print("Please enter a valid number")
     main1()

main1()

def main2(self):
    num2 = input("Enter a number: ")
if not num2.isdigit():
    print("Please enter a valid number")
    main2()

main2()
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this your actual exact indentation as it appears in your original code?

Comment: copy and paste the complete traceback in your question.  It looks like indentation is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditionals are not indented properly. They aren't inside the function definitions, so they will execute right away, before `num1 = ...` ever gets a chance to run.

Try:

```
def main1(self):
    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    if not num1.isdigit():
         print("Please enter a valid number")
         main1()

main1()

def main2(self):
    num2 = input("Enter a number: ")
    if not num2.isdigit():
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        main2()

main2()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your num1 has scope local to the function, so if you want to use it you have to indent properly:

```
def main1(self):
    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")

    if not num1.isdigit():
         print("Please enter a valid number")
main1()
```

Or declare it outside the function